# How to order parent-child relationship with LAMBDA?

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, lambda, tree

What is the right way to write a LINQ query using LAMBDA to put parent items (because of parent-child dependencies) first in the list?

For example expected output should be an ordered list (objecttype named 'Hierarchy) with all fields ID, Parent of the type string):

- ID Parent
- A2 null
- A1 A2
- A5 A2 (dependent on A2)
- A3 A2
- A4 A5 (dependent on A5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Order entities with Parent/Child relationship together in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008347/how-to-order-entities-with-parent-child-relationship-together-in-a-list)

Comment: What is the type of list and objects in the list? From what you wrote, are those strings?

Comment: Why does A5 show up before A1 is the list (While both share the same parent) ? Is there a specific rule for the output ?

Comment: Your wording isn't clear - there is no such thing as a LAMBDA query as far as I know - do you mean a LINQ query using lambda expressions or a LINQ query using query expressions?

Comment: What is the expected output ? And ordered list ? A hierarchy ? What exactly ?

Comment: @Tschareck: List of objects called "Hierarchy" with all fields that are strings.

Comment: @nicholas: LINQ Query using a LAMBDA Expression.

Comment: @user3185569: The output is an ordered list of the objecttype Hierarchy with all fields as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Tree traversal typically requires some kind of recursion, and since C# as a language does not support named lambda expressions (unlike the JavaScript concept of named function expressions), I can think of no way to cleanly perform this task in a pure LINQ query using lambdas.

If you are willing to declare your function delegates externally, it is quite possible. However, this code offers no clear advantage to traditional recursion methods for building up the tree, but does demonstrate a LINQ / lambda version of implementation.

Here is an example using recursion and a lookup table (for efficiency):

```
IEnumerable<ItemType> items = new[]
{
    new ItemType() { ID = "A4", ParentID = "A5"},
    new ItemType() { ID = "A5", ParentID = "A2"},
    new ItemType() { ID = "A1", ParentID = "A2"},
    new ItemType() { ID = "A3", ParentID = "A2"},
    new ItemType() { ID = "A2", ParentID = null },

};

var childrenLookup = items.ToLookup(i => i.ParentID);

Func<ItemType, IEnumerable<ItemType>> preOrderTraverse = null;
preOrderTraverse = new Func<ItemType, IEnumerable<ItemType>>(item =>
{
    var curNode = Enumerable.Repeat(item, 1);
    var childNodes = childrenLookup[item.ID]
        .OrderBy(i => i.ID)                 // Sort siblings by ID
        .SelectMany(preOrderTraverse);

    return Enumerable.Union(curNode, childNodes);
});

var preOrderTraversal = childrenLookup[null].SelectMany(preOrderTraverse);

foreach(var item in preOrderTraversal)
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.ID}, {item.ParentID}");
```

And the output of the code is:

```
A2,
A1, A2
A3, A2
A5, A2
A4, A5
```